# While true loops giving me recursion errors

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, crash, pygame, runtime-error

I'm creating a game with pygame for my CompSci course.  The game is working well, but now I'm trying to make a restart function and I'm getting alot of errors.

The basic outline of what I'm trying to do is:

```
first = True

def check(count):
    if count == 1000:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def start():
    # MAIN MENU
    print ("start")
    count = 0
    while True:
        count += 1
        if check(count) == True:
            Game()

def Game():
    count = 0
    print("Game")
    while True:
       # GAMELOOP
       count += 1
       if check(count) == True:
           restart()

def restart():
    count = 0
    print ("Restart")
    while True:
       # RESTART
       count += 1
       if check(count) == True:
           start()

if first == True:
    first = False
    start()
```

However, whenever I run this, python ultimately crashes with:

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

I'm not sure about how to get around this. I was hoping that someone could suggest another method to do the same thing or something that I've done wrong.

The actual restart and menu functions:

```
def rest(): #Main Menu
 while True:
    pygame.display.update()
    menu.draw()
    if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
            x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            if x >= 255 and x <= 355 and y >= 400 and y <= 450:
                game()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit() 

def game(): #Gameloop
    while True:
        if bottom.time == 0 or bottom.time < 0 :
            game_screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
            restart()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

def restart():
 while True:
    pygame.display.update()
    menu.restart()
    if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
            x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            if x >= 255 and x <= 355 and y >= 400 and y <= 450:
                game_screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
                rest()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a sequence of functions calling each other creating a [indirect recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)#Indirect_recursion).

`start()` counts to 1000 and then calls `Game()`, which counts to 1000 again and then calls `restart()`, whichs also counts to 1000 an then calls `start()`, closing the recursion loop. Once you do not have a stop condition, your recursion goes until reach the depth limit of python's recursion stack, then you get the exception.

As solution, you need to create a stop condition inside of one those functions.

**Edit**

I don't know pygame exactly but, as far as I get from the additional code, to the `for` in `rest()` function (which checks the events) be executed, it needs that the `game()` function returns, which are never happening. You can test this hyphotesis printing something just in the line before the `for` line. Same applies to the restart function.

Comment: I see what your saying, but in my actual program, I have a stop condition.  In each of those functions, I check to see if the player has clicked the x button on the window, and I exit the program if they do.  I still get the the recursion error however.  Would I need to add another method of exiting the loop?

Comment: Without the real code its hard to give you an assertive answer. Does the exception happen even when the user click on the button? The program block to wait for the user interact with the button? With those simple functions the stack limit could be reached really quickly.

Comment: The exception happens as soon as the button is pressed.  The program basically goes unresponsive and then python crashes.  I could add my code in it's entirety if that would help?

Comment: How that button interacts with the code? Is through a callback? Can you post the code snippet which handles the interaction of the butthon with the rest of the code?

Comment: I just added that up to the main post.

Comment: Added some thoughts to my answer. Hope it helps